# Can I paint the top of a glass top stove?

Tags: painting, cleaning, stove

Our previous stove had white speckles over the top.  This helped hide the streaks of casually done wipe ups.

Our present stove is a classic illustration that 'black attracts light coloured dirt'  I am investigating whether it's practical to paint the top of the stove outside the burner areas, either in patterns, with a stencil, a tromp d'oeil sponge.

Such a paint would have to bond to the glass and would need to dry with a smooth finish so that it too was scrub tolerant.

Comment: Have you measured the temperature of the areas you would like to paint while all burners are operating at maximum power?

Comment: I sure do like cleaning my stove top with a razor blade...  Scrubbing and other cleaning would be limited with a coating on top of the glass.

Comment: At the very least you'd want to use temperature resistant paint. They make the stuff and market it in spray cans for BBQ grills and engine blocks.

Comment: Painter here.  You lost me at "bonds to the glass". Paint doesn't do that.  Unless you sandblast the glass.

Comment: I'm 99.9999% confident that if you were to attempt this, it would void whatever warranty remained on the cook top.

Answer (score 1):

No paint will bond well to a glass surface that is so heavily used.

And especially not when subjected to the heat and grease that stove tops generate.

Instead investigate stove top covers.

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017PEELNK) is one that is available in 3 colors

[image]

Comment: This is a fail on two levels:
* It means I have to have a place to put it.
* It means I have to have the stove empty when not in active use.  Under normal circumstances there is at least a tea kettle on the stove.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford  your welcome glad you like it! Take some pictures of the kettle sitting on top of it. And one showing it hanging on the wall behind the stove when you are frying them pickles.

Answer (score 1):

The only absolute permanent way to mark glass that I know of is etching with a glass etching cream.  I've used this for custom drink glasses and casserole dishes (all clear glass), but I don't know what it would look like on a black stove.  It doesn't color the glass, but it would make little frosted specs all over if you sprinkled the etching over the surface.

I can tell you that the frosted markings do sort of disappear when the surface is wet, but always show back up once it dries.

This is more of a long comment because it's not tested for your purpose, but it's something to consider and possibly test in a corner or something.  Before you do anything, realize that it permanently "damages" the glossy surface of the glass and there's no way to undo it if you don't like it.

Any paint will be raised from the surface of the glass which means it can be scraped off and could make cleaning harder.  Maybe someone has some amazing product to try, but there's not a paint I know of that I would put on a cooktop surface.  I believe the white specks and lines on a cooktop are some type of heat-fused ceramic like a glazing.

Comment: Interesting.  Given the difficulty I've had removing ordinary house paint from glass, I figured that there would be something both thinner, and more adhesive.  I suspect you are correct about my original speckles being a ceramic glaze fused to the glass.